# Difference between "I can do that" and "that works for me"

Tags: word-choice

Is there a difference between these two? Which one sounds more polite? Thank you.

Comment: What part of the words does not parse well in your thoughts? In what way would you consider *your ability to do something* to be equivalent to *something that is considered acceptable to you*?

Comment: Hello, 0333! Welcome to ELU and thank you for participating. There’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the tour. Have fun, and we’ll see you around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I can do that" means what it literally says -- you have the ability to perform the suggested action, whether you like the idea or not.

"That works for me" is quite a bit more idiomatic.  It means that the suggestion at least does not conflict with your criteria for a solution to whatever problem is being discussed.  There is a range of meaning, depending on context and tone, between "OK, I guess I can accept that" and "Yes! That's perfect!"

Note that the two are not that close in terms of what's being discussed.  The first involves you actually doing something (and it may be something you're not exactly happy with), while the second means that you accept what is suggested -- it does not, in itself, imply that you will personally "work" on anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"that works for me"* you are agreeing to the idea.

When you say *"I can do that"* you are confirming that you can follow the instructions.

These are subtly different.

I can do something that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

When addressing your boss or college professor use, "I can do that"; when bartering with your landscaper say, "that works for me" (especially when he is to arrive on Saturday).